# Is there any way to create a mini-proxy for http on android?

Tags: android, http, proxy, request

I am working on a HttpClient that posts something to a website. The client looks something like this (based on [this link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)):

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is to create a small proxy service (a VERY simple one) that runs on the same android device and listens for the outgoing HTTP connexions and modifies the POST ( for example change the "id": "12345" into "54321", just for testing purposes), and then pass the HttpRequest to the actual website. How cand I do something like that? I've been googling around but found nothing that could give me an idea how to do it(like a tutorial or something). Can anybody give me an idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write code to achieve this. Instead of writing your own proxy and since you only need it to test you application, you can use the [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) which is a man-in-the-middle [proxy](https://miniproxy.net/?fbclid=IwAR2gShQ2UnkwB_tmU1ruMrgvxTIwEa3ZPqDj1T4CLtNYldRCFQpqjseqBoE) (based on your description that is what you want to achieve). Follow this tutorial to set up your PC as the proxy and the device as your client.

http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/01/how-to-use-mitmproxy-to-read-and-modify-https-traffic-of-your-phone/

Comment: No, the proxy needs to be on the mobile phone. It is a project for school. This is why I really need it to be on the phone. Could I use a service which opens a socket connexion and listens on a specific port number (set by me)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a mini-proxy for HTTP on Android using libraries like NanoHTTPD. Implement a simple server that handles incoming requests and forwards them to the desired destination, acting as a proxy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).